# reduction in confidence interval

Tags: statistics

A large population of interest is known to be comprised of 50% females, 50% males. A study is being planned to estimate the average annual income in this population. The study team suspects that:

1. the average annual female and male incomes differ by $ 5500;
2. the variance of female incomes is 11×10^6 (dollars-squared);
3. the variance of male incomes is 19×10^6 (dollars-squared).

Based on these suppositions, how much of a reduction in confidence interval width would you anticipate if you carry out a stratified sample using proportional allocation rather than a simple random sample (with the same total sample size in either case)? Express your answer as a percent reduction, to one decimal place. (For instance, if the ratio of the two interval widths happened to be 0.6, you would enter an answer of 40.0, since this corresponds to a 40.0 percent reduction.)

I've tried calculating the variance of SRS

= (0.5^2)(1-0.5)(11*10^6)/0.5 +(0.5^2)(1-0.5)(19*10^6)/0.5
= 7 500 000

I don't know if that is correct or not, and I'm unsure what the variance with proportion allocation would be.
The final ratio should be var(prop)/var(SRS).

Comment: The variance of the SRS must account for the $5500 difference in (1).

Comment: How may I account for that as well?

Answer (score 0):

*Extended comment:*  Here is a simulation in R with 20,000 people,
of whom half are women and half are men -- meeting the specifications
you provide. The numerical results may show you what is going on.

The groups you are combining have different means. The variance of the combined group must use the combined mean.

```
 women = rnorm(10000, 55000, sqrt(11)*10^3)
 men =   rnorm(10000, 55000+5500, sqrt(19)*10^3)
 all = c(women, men)
 summary(all)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   42360   54290   57340   57740   60910   77920 
 sd(women);  sd(men);  sd(all)
 ## 3323.203
 ## 4454.663
 ## 4799.94
```